# SQL 2008 Merge Statement - 2008 Source - 2005 Target

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, merge

Is it safe to say that if I'm trying to create a MERGE statment and run from SQL 2008, both the source and target database must be SQL 2008 or later?

I'm trying to run a MERGE statement on SQL 2008 where the source is a SQL 2008 database and the target is 2005...but I get red squiggles under all 2005 table references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running this on linked servers? Your second server must be in the following query result:

```
select * from sys.servers
```

If so, I suggest you create temporary tables in your 2008 server from the tables in 2005 in your instance. Or better yet, create Synonyms. Here is a sample code:

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[Appointments] FOR [DevOffline].[dbo].[Appointments]
```

Comment: Yes, it is on linked servers and I do see it in the result set.  I tried using the CREATE SYNONYM but I get a message that reads "Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE."   Source = 2008, Destination is 2005.  I think i'll have to try it the old fashion way with a couple of statemets.